# Not getting JSON's full attribute value of a json property

Tags: python, json

I am extracting some data from my JSON file placed locally on my PC:
and structure is:

**JSON DATA SAMPLE**

```
{ "totalRecords": 1, 
  "items": [{
            "name": "Services Ltd",
            "country": "GB",
            "city": "Evesham",
            "zip": "WR11 1BY",
            "address": "Northwick House\r\rCoopers Lane"
      }]
}
```

**Python Script**

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
fileName = r'naturesmenu.json'
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)    
dataData = data["items"]
c = 1
for i in dataData:
    # pprint(i)
    name = i['name']
    address = i['address']
    print(address)
```

for:

```
address = i['address']
```

**Output should be:**

```
Northwick House\r\rCoopers Lane
```

or if it removes/ has the effect of carriage return then output should look like this:

```
Northwick House

Coopers Lane
```

but I'm getting only this output:

```
Coopers Lane
```

not the full value corresponding to `address`.
What am I doing wrong can someone point out? thanks

Comment: `\r` is not a line break. Use `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carriage return without newline goes to the beginning of the line and then starts overwriting the same line, it doesn't go to the next line. So `Coopers Lane` is being displayed over `Northwick House`, and the output you'll see is

```
Coopers Laneuse
```

Change the JSON file so it contains `\n` instead of `\r`, that's a newline escape sequence.

Comment: yeah wasn't having an idea that it happened. thanks for correcting sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose `replace`

```
dataData = data["items"]
c = 1
for i in dataData:
    # pprint(i)
    name = i['name']
    print(name)
    address = i['address'].replace('\r',' ')
    print(address)

# 'Northwick House Coopers Lane'
```

Or, `\n` in `replace` if you want output in new line

```
address = i['address'].replace('\r','\n')

# Northwick House
# Coopers Lane
```

Comment: yeah, the concept explained by @Barmer sir. confused about of whom answer should I accept. The above one explained well and this is corrected before that.